# Is there a static tree component in Wicket?

Tags: java, tree, wicket

Is anyone aware of a stateless tree component in Apache Wicket that works similarly to the `JTree`/`TreeModel` concept in Swing? I'm specifically looking for a static tree, i.e. no fancy AJAX or the like — just a plain and simple way of displaying a tree model.

Answer (score 2):

You say you want a static, AJAX-less tree... does it even have to be a formal tree component? If not, you might be able to use recursive panels to mimic a tree, as illustrated [here](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/nested/?2) in the Wicket Examples ([source code](http://wicketstuff.org/wicket/nested/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.wicket.examples.source.SourcesPage?4&SourcesPage_class=org.apache.wicket.examples.nested.Home)). It really depends on your use case, though.

I was also going to suggest going ahead and using one of the fancy trees, like [this one](http://wicketstuff.org/wicket/nested/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.wicket.examples.ajax.builtin.tree.SimpleTreePage?0), and overriding the behavior of clicking on the tree to "do nothing." Unfortunately, it looks like the expand/collapse methods are built in at such a deep level that that's not possible. There is no built-in class that does exactly what you want.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your suggestions. I think I might dig into some of the tree components out there and bake my own version minus all the AJAX goodness. The wicket-tree project (http://code.google.com/p/wicket-tree) looks like a good base to investigate.